# ThreadEnforcer usage in Event Bus register method

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

can anyone simplify what this code does to register an object to able to listen to events posted by the event bus? Also, do you need to wrap the post call in a handler to contact the UI thread ?? The main question is what is the thread enforcer doing here

```
 public void register(Object object) {
     if (object == null) {
             throw new NullPointerException("Object to register must 
           not be null.");
        }
         enforcer.enforce(this);

Map<Class<?>, EventProducer> foundProducers = 
    handlerFinder.findAllProducers(object);
for (Class<?> type : foundProducers.keySet()) {

  final EventProducer producer = foundProducers.get(type);
  EventProducer previousProducer = producersByType.putIfAbsent(type, producer);
  //checking if the previous producer existed
  if (previousProducer != null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Producer method for type " + type
      + " found on type " + producer.target.getClass()
      + ", but already registered by type " + previousProducer.target.getClass() + ".");
  }
  Set<EventHandler> handlers = handlersByType.get(type);
  if (handlers != null && !handlers.isEmpty()) {
    for (EventHandler handler: handlers) {
      dispatchProducerResultToHandler(handler, producer);
    }
  }
}

Map<Class<?>, Set<EventHandler>> foundHandlersMap = handlerFinder.findAllSubscribers(object);
for (Class<?> type : foundHandlersMap.keySet()) {
  Set<EventHandler> handlers = handlersByType.get(type);
  if (handlers == null) {
    //concurrent put if absent
    Set<EventHandler> handlersCreation = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<EventHandler>();
    handlers = handlersByType.putIfAbsent(type, handlersCreation);
    if (handlers == null) {
        handlers = handlersCreation;
    }
  }
  final Set<EventHandler> foundHandlers = foundHandlersMap.get(type);
  handlers.addAll(foundHandlers);
}

for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, Set<EventHandler>> entry : foundHandlersMap.entrySet()) {
  Class<?> type = entry.getKey();
  EventProducer producer = producersByType.get(type);
  if (producer != null && producer.isValid()) {
    Set<EventHandler> foundHandlers = entry.getValue();
    for (EventHandler foundHandler : foundHandlers) {
      if (!producer.isValid()) {
        break;
      }
      if (foundHandler.isValid()) {
        dispatchProducerResultToHandler(foundHandler, producer);
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
```